# How to decode from 1D barcode image

Tags: ios, swift

Below code is only worked for decoding from a QR code image, not applicable for 1D barcode.

I don't want to use any third-party library.

Is it possible to get any `CIQRCodeFeature` for Barcode image?

your help is appreciated.

```
func scanCodeFromImage(image: UIImage) -> String? {

    guard let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]), let ciImage = CIImage(image: image), let features = detector.features(in: ciImage) as? [CIQRCodeFeature] else { return nil }

    var qrCodeText = ""

    for feature in features {
        if let message = feature.messageString {
            qrCodeText += message
        }
    }

    return qrCodeText
}
```

Comment: for CIDetector, as far as i know, there is no way to read a barcode.
If you're using iOS 11 and above as your deployment target, you can use Vison API and create a `VNDetectBarcodesRequest`.

Comment: 1D barcodes are not QR codes, therefore you cannot use `CIDetectorTypeQRCode`.

Comment: @Symon You can make use of AVfoundation and scan image. The result of bar code will be available in AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate methods

Comment: @AceRivera thanks for your advice, Using VNDetectBarcodesRequest we can get payloadStringValue which is the basic decoded value of barcode image

Comment: 1-D barcode images can be read using Apple Vision Api. Found Answer From This Link: https://codevampires.com/how-to-get-decoded-value-from-1-d-barcode-image-swift/

Answer (score 1):

No third party libraries are needed for this, Apple provides the [AVFoundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation)

Follow [this](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/how-to-create-a-simple-qrcode-barcode-scanner-app-in-ios-swift-fd9970a70859) tutorial for a better understanding of how to get it working, all you have to do is change the type of barcode you want to scan, and you can select multiple different types or just one type. This could also be done with images or straight from the camera without using a third party library.